# How to select actual year in Oracle Date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to select the employees that registered in the company this year; the field is a date type(field name :datemp) so i used :

```
SELECT employee_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE datemp BETWEEN to_date(01-JAN-2015) AND to_date (31-DEC-2015)
```

is there another method i can say that the year of a field that has a date type is in the actual year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull  it from `sysdate`

```
SELECT employee_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM datemp) = EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

```
select employee_name
from   emploees
where  trunc(datemp, 'yyyy') = to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'); -- or trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') if you need it to refer to this year
```

(or even ... `to_char(datemp, 'yyyy') = '2015';`)

Bear in mind that if you do use a function on the datemp column, any indexes on that column will no longer be used (unless there's a function-based index that matches the new function on the column).

Answer (score 1):

If there is an index on your `datemp` column, this *may* perform better using a range scan, depending on how many years of data are in the table:

```
SELECT employee_name
FROM employees
WHERE datemp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')
AND datemp < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY'),12);
```

(But, in practice it's such a wide date range it'll probably still do a full table scan anyway.)